# Invalid hook call error. Trying react-native app navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation

I'm creating an app in react native and I'm struggling a lot with the navigation between screens. This is what I have so far.
My app.tsx =>

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Header from './components/header';
import Home from './screens/home/home';
import Login from './screens/login/login';
import ScheduleBody from './screens/schedule/body';
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Navigation, { StackParams } from './components/navigation';
import colors from './components/colors';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import PersonalRecords from './screens/pr/personalRecords';
import UserPage from './screens/user/userPage';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Body from './screens/home/body';
import Protein from './screens/protein/protein';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
type HeaderNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<StackParams, 'Schedule'>;
type FooterNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<StackParams, 'Protein'>;
const navigation = useNavigation<HeaderNavigationProp>();

type Props = {
  navigation: HeaderNavigationProp;
};


const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const [initialRouteName, setInitialRouteName] = React.useState('Login');

  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    if (user) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
      setInitialRouteName('Home');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
    checkLoggedIn();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!loggedIn ? <Header navigation={navigation} /> : null}
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Schedule" component={ScheduleBody} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="PersonalRecords" component={PersonalRecords} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} /> 
            <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserPage} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Protein" component={Protein} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    {!loggedIn ? <Footer /> : null}
    </View>
  );
};
```

My navigation.tsx =>

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

export type StackParams = {
  Home: undefined;
  Schedule: undefined;
  User: undefined;
  Protein: undefined;
  PersonalRecords: undefined;

}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<StackParams>();

export default  Stack;
```

My header.tsx =>

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import colors from './colors';
import { calendar, activeWorkout, restDay, streak_25 } from '../assets/assets';
import { StackParams } from './navigation';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type HeaderNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<StackParams, 'Schedule'>;

type Props = {
    navigation: HeaderNavigationProp;
  };

const Header = ({navigation}: Props) => {
  const [hasWorkout, setHasWorkout] = React.useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setHasWorkout(false);
  }, []);

  const toggleActiveWorkout = () => {
    setHasWorkout(!hasWorkout);
  };

  const handleCalender = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Schedule');
  };

  return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.centerContainer} >
            {hasWorkout ? (
                <Image style={styles.textLeft} source={ activeWorkout } />
            ) : (
                <Image style={styles.textLeft} source={ restDay } />
                )}
            <Text style={styles.textCenter}>25<Image style={styles.streak} source={streak_25}/></Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textRight} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={handleCalender}>
                <Image
                source={calendar}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

This is one page where I want to use the navigation. But I can't find a solution for this to work. The current error I'm encountering.

```
 ERROR  Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null, js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "PumpPal_app" with {"rootTag":71}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "PumpPal_app" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You called useNavigation outside of a component. Please place it back in the app() or inside a component that requires it.
    `const navigation = useNavigation<HeaderNavigationProp>();`

Answer (score 0):

**From react official documentation:**

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions Don’t call Hooks from regular
> JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> ✅ Call Hooks from custom
> Hooks

So based on this, on your App component you have made a mistake, because useNavigation hook is used neither inside a functional component, nor inside a custom hook.

Simply move the line:

```
const navigation = useNavigation<HeaderNavigationProp>();
```

inside the the App component, and this error will be resolved.